# Задача: составить оффлайн опрос в виде html страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Задача такова, что нужно составить опрос в виде html страницы с использованием JS, чтобы результаты опроса сохранить в json формате и после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" должно создаваться письмо для отправки на определённую почту. Мне не нужно решение, если можете, помогите ссылками, что мне нужно изучить для решения задачи (помимо работы с json).
P.S. Клиент будет получать письмо с html файлом, открывать его в браузере и проходить ОФФЛАЙН опрос.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит "оффлайн". Если нужно, чтобы отправлялось письмо, это в любом случае онлайн. А так алгоритм простой: делаете на html-странице тест (удобнее всего в виде формы с разными инпутами), по нажатию на кнопку "Отправить" отправляете данные из формы на сервер, а уже с сервера отправляете данные на почту. Изучить надо html (формы) + основы js + основы php

Comment: @humster_spb клиент будет получать письмо с html файлом, проходить опрос, после нажатия на кнопочку должно формироваться письмо, и ему нужно будет лишь отправить его.

Comment: @FreddieFazber, если подразумевается отправка письма, то это УЖЕ не оффлайн опрос. по такой же логике любой статичный сайт можно называть оффлайн сайтом.

Comment: @dasauser письмо будет отправляться через почтовую программу клиента, файлом, а не с использованием формы на страничке.

Comment: @FreddieFazber, это я понял, но оффлайн подразумевает отсутствие подключения к сети,т.е. если вы отправляете на сервер данные по интернету, то это уже не оффлайн тест. да и как вы будете отправлять письмо человеку, если у него сети нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, как-то так, например:

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', 'mailto:admin@test.ru ?subject=Результаты теста &Body={"name":"'+$('#name').val()+'", "age":"'+$('#age').val()+'"}');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
  <input type="number" name="age" id="age" /><br />
  <a href="">Отправить</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример

Comment: @FreddieFazber, так это то, что Вам нужно?

Comment: полагаю, что да

Answer (score 0):

```css
label { display: block }
```

```html
<form action="mailto:some-bot@mail.ru">
  <p>
    Вопрос 1
    <label><input name=q1 type=radio required value=a11>Ответ 1</label>
    <label><input name=q1 type=radio required value=a12>Ответ 2</label>
    <label><input name=q1 type=radio required value=a13>Ответ 3</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    Вопрос 2
    <label><input name=q2 type=radio required value=a21>Ответ 1</label>
    <label><input name=q2 type=radio required value=a22>Ответ 2</label>
    <label><input name=q2 type=radio required value=a23>Ответ 3</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type=submit value=Готово!>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо, кэп. Уточню: как составить опрос, в плане, в каком формате, я знаю. Меня интересует именно создание скрипта на js для того, чтобы ответы собирались в json и создавалось письмо для отправки на почту.